# How does the equation for min heap array indexing work?

Tags: heaps

I've been reading about min heaps, currently looking at [this article](https://codeburst.io/implementing-a-complete-binary-heap-in-javascript-the-priority-queue-7d85bd256ecf), and I am very confused by something.

The article makes the following statement:

> If a given node is located at index 'x' in the array, its left child
>   exists at index = 2x, and its right child exists at index = 2x + 1. 
>   Each node's parent exists at index = x / 2 (rounded down).

It gives this example:

[image]

This min heap is represented in the array `[100, 19, 36, 17, 3, 25, 1, 2, 7]`.

But this doesn't jive with the preceding statement about indexing. `36` can be found at index `2`, and `2 * 2` is `4`. But index `4` is 3-- the right child of the 19 node, not the left child of the 36 node.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start indexing at $1$, then everything will be fine.

Want to start at $0$? That is no problem, but one has to adjust the formula's. Children of $x$ can be found at $2x+1$ and $2x+2$.